# How to read a file in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to implement a simple search function which when user input text in the box, it will go through the `json file [large.js]` to see if there's any matching record. If yes, the result will be shown.

The problem is when i run the py file, there's an error `No such file or directory "large"`

Any Idea will be great. Thanks

> Below is the python code  [application.py]

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
WORDS = []
with open("large", "r") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        WORDS.append(line.rstrip()) 
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/search")
def search():
    q = request.args.get("q")
    words = [word for word in WORDS if word.startswith(q)]
    return jsonify(words)
```

> Below is the HTML code [templates/index.html]

```
<input type="text">
<ul></ul>
<script src ="large.js"></script>
<script>
let input = document.querySelector("input")
input.onkeyup = function (){
let html = "";
if (input.value){
for (word of WORDS){
if (word.startsWith(input.value)){
html += "<li>" + word +"</li>";
}} }
document.querySelector("ul").innerHTML = html;
};
</script>
```

> large.js file that contain the json

```
let WORDS = [
"a",
"abandon",
"abandoned",
"ability",
"able"]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try giving the absolute location of the `large.js` file?

Comment: yes, i did with no luck

Comment: As I understand from the error, it is not finding the file. Probably the path issue. The other thing is, you're storing `json` in `javascript` file. If only purpose of file storing `json` data, why not use `.json` extension?

Comment: Save the js file as py file with the list, you can import `WORDS` which is efficient

Comment: @epiphany In what folder is the `large.js` stored in the structure of your app?

Comment: Edited Please take a look at the snap capture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a folder called `static` and then inside the `static` folder create another folder called `js` and put your `large.js` file in there
2. In your `templates/index.html` change this
   `<script src ="large.js"></script>`
   to this
   `<script src ="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/large.js') }}"></script>`

After which your application structure should look something like

[image]

And then try something like below in your code and let me know what happens

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
data_file = os.path.join(basedir, 'static/js/large.js')

WORDS = []
with open(data_file, "r") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        WORDS.append(line.rstrip())

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/search")
def search():
    q = request.args.get("q")
    words = [word for word in WORDS if word.startswith(q)]
    return jsonify(words)
```

Comment: PS :even if i manually input words in the WORDS array eg WORDS = ["a", "b"], still the input box wont show the matching results

Comment: @epiphany I have edited my answer to address what I think the issue is, try again and let me know how the new solution goes

Comment: For a better explanation, you can follow this official flask [tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/) or just read through the official [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/)